# Why would this code crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS during NSArray InitWithObjects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

Notice in the code below, the two NSLOG statements.  The "aaa" gets printed out but the "bbb" never does.  Instead, the simulator crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I know that this typically means that the object I am trying to access has been prematurely released.   I just can't figure out what is wrong...

Updated:

here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface vcAddCat : UIViewController  <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

IBOutlet UIPickerView * pickerView;
NSArray * _weights;
NSArray * _categories;
IBOutlet UILabel *lastCat;
IBOutlet UILabel *lastWeight;
```

}

I do not have any @property or @synthesize lines for either array...

Here are two snips from my .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    _categories=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Homework",@"Quizzes",@"Tests", @"Mid-Term Exam", nil];
;

    NSLog(@"aaa");

    _weights=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19", @"20", @"21",@"22",@"23", @"24", @"25", nil];


    NSLog(@"bbb");
```

..and here is where I release the arrays...

```
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[_categories release];
[_weights release];
NSLog(@">>> Leaving %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

}

Comment: You should post the actual stack trace that you receive. This will indicate where the crash occurred. Are you releasing these ivars in viewDidUnload? If not, you're leaking memory here (though that generally would not cause a crash).

Comment: you got `11` twice in your _weights array

Comment: are you sure _weights is an NSArray object?

Comment: Rob, I'm not seeing a stack trace from debugger console.  It simply exits with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error line.  Am I missing something with the debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK - loser alert.

Sorry, guys.  All was working when I tested early on with only 10 objects to insert.  Once I got it going, I added the rest of the objects (11 - 100) and that's when it crashed.  When I posted the code above, I truncated the object list at 25 items - too redundant, it seemed.

Well, objects 26, 36, 46, etc all had a typo in them where I'd omitted the preceding '@' before the string value.

Fixed that and I'm back on track.

Thanks for your help and sorry about the lame error.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Look the problem is somewhere in your _weights array.Debug the code& check when you reach the second NSLog, whats the value of array , is it properly retained.Have you made the array as property & synthesized it

In your .h file

```
NSArray *_weights;

@property( nonatomic, retain ) NSArray  *_weights;
```

In your .m file

```
@synthesize _weights
```

Comment: Well, since the code exits before it gets to the second NSLog, I can not mouse-over _weights in order to check it.  However, when I mouse over _categories, it is in good shape.  Both NSArrays are declared in the .h as NSArray * _categories, etc... without any corresponding @property or @synthesize statements.  Should I be making these properties with (nonatomic, retain)???

Comment: check your array declaration!.I would suggest you just to check whether problem is due to array declaration.Make_weights array as local.I checked it making it local it worked perfectly.If you are making it global then

Comment: Yes, I have tried the code above, exactly.  Actually, I tried that before posting initially.  No joy.  The strange thing is that all this worked with early test data of only 10 entries... When I went past 16 entries, it crapped out....

Comment: @swastik - not sure how you mean when you say local.  How do I declare/implement it in that way?

Answer (score 0):

I just put that exact code into an app I have and it ran just fine. I reached the "bbb". So, the question I have is, how have you defined _weights ? In my class I was using:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
   NSArray* _weights;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls change your dealloc to

```
- (void)dealloc {
[_categories release];
[_weights release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Never call `[super dealloc];` before releasing other objects of the class.

Comment: yes, still.  It prints out the "aaa" but not the "bbb" from the nslog statements - same as before.   crapola.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your arguments settings for your executable and turning NSZombieEnabled to YES. This will stop your program at the exact line causing the bad memory access.

Comment: thanks!   I will look to use this in the future.  I did find my error - I was loading my array with NSString objects such as @"one", @"two", and "three"...   Notice that I left off the '@' on the third object...  I had one of those in my objects...  sorry for the run around.